# how to generate img with same spacing

Tags: graphviz

I generated a graph from this output:

```
digraph G {
    { rank = same; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; };
    2 -> 3 [label="hi there"];
}
```

However the label is long, which results in the space between nodes 2 and 3 being greater than the space between the other nodes. How can I make it so that the space between all other nodes matches the one between 2 and 3 (that is, the biggest of them all).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xlabel` instead of a label, and increase the separation between nodes of the same rank with `nodesep`:

> In dot, this specifies the minimum space between two adjacent nodes in
>   the same rank, in inches.

```
digraph G {
    nodesep=0.8;
    forcelabels=true;
    { rank = same; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; };
    2 -> 3 [xlabel="hi there"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What you mean is that I need to set the distance between each node, with nodesep, depending on the label? I would rather have something that adjusts to the size of the label (such as that the distance between every node is equal to the maximum length of the labels) rather than setting it manually.

Comment: No, this sets the minimum distance for all nodes in the same rank, not for a single node. But yes, this has to be set manually depending on your longest label (trial and error). Of course this is a hack...

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in advance what the label size is going to be, so I can't do trial and error on it.