# change arrow direction

Tags: graphviz, dot

I generated a graph from this output:

```
digraph G {
    { rank = same; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; };
    2 -> 3 [label="hi there"];
}
```

I would however like the arrow to be from 3 to 2 instead. I tried changing the direction of the arrow (<-) but it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing edge direction in dot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424555/changing-edge-direction-in-dot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I've found it, all I have to do is use [dir=back].

However I still have not figured out how to make the distance between the nodes be the same between all nodes, it's bigger between 2 and 3. See [how to generate img with same spacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792042/how-to-generate-img-with-same-spacing)